# Is "vocabulary words" just the same as "vocabulary"? If not, what is the difference?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Sometimes I see the word "vocabulary words" as in "3,000 Core Vocabulary Words" or "262 SAT Vocab Words You Must Know" for instance, but I feel that the expression is a bit redundant. Just "vocabulary or "words" sounds fine to me. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vocabulary, in the sense you mean, is uncountable. So you can't use "3000 vocabulary" or "3000 vocabularies" for that. You can say 3000 words, but that might mean a text with 3000 total words, many of which are repeated. So, "3000 vocabulary words" is a reasonable way to specify that many unique words to add to your vocabulary.

Comment: I see. All is clear now. Thank you, Jack.